# How to calculate perimeter of a rectangle without using addition?

Tags: geometry

If given the width and height of a rectangle is it possible to calculate the perimeter without using addition or subtraction?

If not, why is this the case?

The only luck I've had is for trivial cases, such as a squares (4*width).

Comment: With $a$ and $b$ as side lengths, does $P=2ln(e^{a}e^{b})$ count?

Comment: What motivates you to find such a way?`

Comment: Enter the values into a calculator.  Then you are not doing the adding; the calculator is.

Comment: ... so I'd say, "not really".  Ultimately the perimeter is 2(a + b).  You can find clever and creative ways to hide the addition (@user2825632 was *very* clever and creative)  but ... it's always there.  Even 4*s is "just" 2(s + s).

Comment: Does $2 \int_{-a}^{b} dx$ count?

Comment: @fleablood The problem can be solved in uncountably infinite tries by checking all 2nd degree monic polynomials until the unique one is found which has the given width and height as its roots. Then the perimeter will be minus twice the coefficient of the linear term. (Disclaimer: not even half-serious, of course.)

Comment: @Lovsovs I thought of the question when trying to reverse the problem "Do multiplication by addition" into "Do addition by multiplication". The perimeter of a rectangle is the cleanest geometric representation I could think of. It seems like there should be some relation between the area of the rectangle, the proportions and the perimeter - but I am no mathematician.

Comment: `Do addition by multiplication` @user2825632's comment gave you what's essentially the equivalent of [Logarithm tables, slide rules, and historical applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithm_tables.2C_slide_rules.2C_and_historical_applications) in reverse.